# Webscraping: How to extract just the Information that I need

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have to scrape some information from the congress.gov site (https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%22115%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22bills%22%7D&page=113). 
I am not able to extract the information on the Sponsors.

```
import os
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
x=0
y=0
index=0;
mydirectory= '/Users/Antonio/Desktop/statapython assignment'
congress115 =os.path.join(mydirectory, '115congress.csv')
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Make_America_Great_Again',
                    'From': 'Donald'}
with open('115congress.csv', 'w') as f:
    fwriter=csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    fwriter.writerow(['Spons'])
    for j in range(1, 114):
        hrurl='https://www.congress.gov/search?q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22legislation%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%22115%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22bills%22%7D&page='+str(j)
        hrpage=requests.get(hrurl, headers=headers)
        data=hrpage.text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
        #index=0;
        for q in soup.findAll('span', {'class':'result-item'}):
            for a in q.findAll('a', href=True, text=True, target='_blank'):
                if a==y:
                    continue
                y=a
                Spons=a['href']
                print(Spons)
```

What I get is something like this (I will just report one of the 7401 results for sake of brevity)

```
/member/michael-enzi/E000285
```

while I need

```
Sen. Enzi, Michael B. [R-WY]
```

I am sorry if I put down something in the wrong way but this is my first question on here.
Any help will bre gratly appreciate.

Comment: It looks like you are getting the href, what element holds Sen. Enzi, Michael B. [R-WY] ?

Comment: Do you only need sponsors without associating that with any other info e.g. bill name? Also, what about co-sponsors?

Comment: Thank for your reply I need "Sen Enzi Micheal B [R-WY], but I am able to split the part about the party ("R") and the State (WY") on Python. For the Cosponsors I guess the code would be basically the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract text from `<a>` tag (instead of `href` attribute):

```
...
Spons = a.text
```

Comment: I m a dumbass. Thank you so much, it works perfectly.